# reuse the auto inserted generated field in another field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm working on an application that will generate folios for some form filling that the user will make,
internally I will handle a documentId which will be auto incremented, however I have to generate the client's
folio in a diffennt format
**Example:**

```
Folio 100613A100
10 - day
06 - month
13 - year
A - if regular 
E - if special 
100 - AI number
```

Basically I can the first 7 digits from my PHP code however since I don't know what the AI number will be I can create
this value until the insert is done,

My current approach is to do a insert without populating that field and right after the insert use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` 
to generate the Folio and update the table, but this  looks kind of an overhead to me so I'm wondering if there any hidden gem
in MySql that would allow to use the AI value on the insert.

Note that I can't use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` id **before** the insert as the app will have concurrent access, my implementation is working just fine and I don't have any issue with it I'm just wondering if is possible for the sake of gaining a little bit of knowldege.

Comment: Explain why you see this as a overhead?

Comment: I'm hitting the DB twice while I'm generating the data for just 1 record

Comment: The second hit to get the last insert id is basically zero work for the DB.  While it is overhead in the purest sense it is probably among the cheapest DB operation you can make, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: why not append the id when retrieving the data? seems redundant to have the same id twice in the same row

Comment: Just to clarify do I understand correctly those are two columns in one table: `documentid` which is `auto_increment` and `folio` that should be generated?

Comment: @peterm that's correct sir

Comment: Once assigned can folio be changed? Is it fixed format? meaning for an id = 1 folio will end with `1` or `001`?

Comment: Not in the business logic, the folios should be unique and there shouldnt be any change after they are created, and there is not fixed format, the ID will not have leading zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal generating folio numbers at insertion time using `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and a separate table (if you don't mind) for sequencing.

First of all sequencing table

```
CREATE TABLE table1_seq 
  (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Your actual table

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
  (`id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
   `folio` VARCHAR(32)
   ...
  );
```

A trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table1_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON Table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  SET NEW.folio = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d%m%y'), UPPER(NEW.folio), NEW.id);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now you can insert a new record

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (`folio`, ...)
VALUES ('a', ...), ('e', ...);
```

And you'll have in your table1

```
| ID |    FOLIO |...
-----------------...
|  1 | 160613A1 |...
|  2 | 160613E2 |...
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3333/1)** demo.

**Another way** is just to wrap your `INSERT` and `UPDATE` in a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_table1_insert (IN folio_type VARCHAR(1), ...)
BEGIN
  DECLARE newid INT DEFAULT 0;
  START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT INTO table1 (id, ...) VALUES (NULL, ...);
  SET newid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  UPDATE table1 
     SET folio = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d%m%y'), UPPER(folio_type), newid)
   WHERE id = newid;
  COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then insert new records using this stored procedure

```
CALL sp_table1_insert ('a',...);
CALL sp_table1_insert ('e',...);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca958/1)** demo for that.

Comment: @isJustMe You're very welcome :) See updated answer for a plain SP approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **AFTER INSERT TRIGGER**. Refer to this manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: Can you show how? In MySql you can't change `NEW` values in `AFTER INSERT` trigger.

Comment: What do you mean you "can't change new values in after insert trigger"?

Comment: I mean **exactly** what I said: in `AFTER INSERT` trigger you have an access to the value of an auto_incremented column but you can't change any of column values.